# Arrow within a signal (timing diagram)

Tags: diagrams, timing-diagrams

I want to draw a Manchester code and need arrows to better show the falling and rising flag within the signal, something like that:

[image]

In LaTeX, it is possible to use the package `timing`. Is it possible to draw an arrow within a timing diagram using the package `timing`? If not, how else is it possible?

Comment: Hi, could you accept one of the answers now. I think simply forgot to do this.

Answer (score 8):

There is a `tikz`-based package for drawing timing diagram called `tikz-timing`.
With it logic levels can be given as letters like H for high and L for low. For your case I recommend the clock character C together with the `clockarrows` library. I aware that you signal isn't a clock, but other signals don't have arrows in this package. The C letter changes its logic level every time it is used. In lowercase its length its only half the width. You signal can be written simply as `cCCccCccCCc`, beside some start position issue I just discovered.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary{clockarrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}[scale=2,timing/.cd,
        c/dual arrows,c/arrow tip=latex,
        c/arrow pos=.7,
        metachar={v}{[timing/c/no arrows]c[timing/c/dual arrows]},
        slope=0]
    \shortstack[l]{Manchester-Codierung:\\(bi-phase)} 
      &h 0c0h0l 0c CCcvCcvCCc \\
 \extracode
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
       \vertlines[help lines,brown]{}
       \foreach [count=\x] \b in {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0} {
            \node [below,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,inner ysep=2pt] at (\x-.5,0) {\b};
       }
   \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

You can do what you want using tikz. I drew a rough picture like the one in your example using the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %red vertical lines
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,8} {
        \draw[color=red] (\x,0.5) -- +(0,3);  };

    %black lines with arrows
    \draw[very thick,->] (0,2.5) -- +(0.5,0) -- +(0.5,-0.5);
    \draw[very thick,->] (0.5,2) -- +(0,-0.5) -- +(1,-0.5) -- +(1,0);
    \draw[very thick,->] (1.5,2) -- +(0,0.5) -- +(1,0.5) -- +(1,0);
    \draw[very thick,->] (2.5,2) -- +(0,-0.5) -- +(0.5,-0.5) -- +(0.5,0.5) -- +(1,0.5) --+(1,0);
    \draw[very thick,->] (3.5,2) -- +(0,-0.5) -- +(1,-0.5) -- +(1,0);
    \draw[very thick,->] (4.5,2) -- +(0,0.5) -- +(0.5,0.5) -- +(0.5,-0.5) -- +(1,-0.5) -- +(1,0);
    \draw[very thick,->] (5.5,2) -- +(0,0.5) -- +(1,0.5) -- +(1,0);
    \draw[very thick,->] (6.5,2) -- +(0,-0.5) -- +(1,-0.5) -- +(1,0);
    \draw[very thick] (7.5,2) -- +(0,0.5) -- +(0.5,0.5);

    %numbers
    \path (0.5,1) node{1};
    \path (1.5,1) node{0};
    \path (2.5,1) node{1};
    \path (3.5,1) node{1};
    \path (4.5,1) node{0};
    \path (5.5,1) node{0};
    \path (6.5,1) node{1};
    \path (7.5,1) node{0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Of course, the code above is inefficient and can be improved, but this will give you an idea of how TiKz works so that if you can't find a solution with timing, this will do.